# Prevent Vuetify from printing to console "[Vuetify] Image load failed"

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify to load an image:

```html
<v-img :src="this.imageUrl" :lazy-src="defaultImage" v-on:error="onError" :width="100" :height="150"></v-img>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    defaultImage: require('@/assets/images/defaultImage.png'),
    useFallbackImage: false
  }
},
computed: {
  imageUrl: function() {
    return !this.useFallbackImage ? `http://foo/v1.0/bar/${this.propId}` : this.defaultImage;
  }
},
methods: {
  onError: function() {
    this.useFallbackImage = true;
  }
}
```

I don't know if the image exists, so I am letting the browser try, and if it doesn't then fallback to the default. This works just fine, but Vuetify annoyingly prints a bunch of junk to the console:

"[Vuetify] Image load failed ... found in ..."

I looked in the source code and it looks like they are indiscriminately printing to the console whenever an error even before the handler. But I thought I would try -- does anybody know of a way to squelch Vuetify here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe able to do something like this:

```
import VImg from 'vuetify/lib/components/VImg'

export default VImg.extend({
  name: 'VImageWrapper',
  methods: {
    onError() {
     // leave empty
    }
  }
})
```

Taken from this thread:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6755